# Client application to get the roles of a logged in user (JAAS)

Tags: java, jboss, jaas

I have the following code working to run a Java (SE) application (not on server), where the login should be done using an existing JBoss server (I am tied to 4.2.3) running with JAAS authentication. I started with a simple console application to perform the login and later integrate this functionality to the application.

I use a snippet - found [here](http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/02/19/perform-a-jaas-programmatic-login-in-jboss-try-to-solve-the-empty-remote-user-problem/) - to perform the login:

```
JaasJbossConfiguration.activateConfiguration();
UsernamePasswordHandler handler =
  new UsernamePasswordHandler("userName", "passWord");
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("myrealm", handler);
try {
     lc.login();
} catch (LoginException e) {
 // Authentication failed.
}
```

This works like a charm. Now I want to extend my application and permit access only for users in special role. Is there any way to get the roles of the user from the Java application side or permit authentication only for those users?

Comment: What type is your application (command line app)? What does it call on JBoss (EJBs)?

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear. So, yes, currently it's just a  command line app. For the start we won't need session handling - just granting access for the user or not. So there is no need to call on EJBs and use the user's  login-session - if you meant such thing with "What does it call on JBOSS (EJBs)?"

Comment: If you are not calling EJBs, what else do you do with JBoss (after login)? Which JBoss login module are you using?

Comment: Later on we want to call some services, mbeans and so on, but for now we just want to exchange our local login module with a server based one. I use the ClientLoginModule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You could prevent authentication based on a (non-existing) role, if the (custom) login module checks for it.
- But normally, if there is a user with a matching password, the user is authenticated (possibly with no roles at all). So normally *authentication* (user/password) is not linked with *authorization* (roles).

---

- In EJBs you can use declarative authorization based on roles (see `@RolesAllowed`)
- As for EJBs: You can call `EJBContext.getCallerPrincipal()` and `EJBContext.isUserInRole()` in an EJB
- As for a servlet/JSP: you can call `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()` and `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()`
- As for stand-alone applications, I am not aware of an API.
- So the standard API only allows to check against a role. If you want to get the list of roles, there is no official API.

Anyway, look into the source of a login module (for example: `DatabaseServerLoginModule`). Then write an EJB which does the same (regarding roles lookup), and which returns the list of roles to your stand-alone application.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to make use of JEE security provided by containers (mostly JAAS). The advantage is, you can change the authentication and authorization to any new technology with just configuration, without impacting other part of application. I give an example using JBoss AS

1. Add security constraints in web.xml

   Web Resources
           /*
       
       
           ROLE_ADDUPDATE
           ROLE_SEARCH
           ROLE_ADMIN
       


       ROLE_ADMIN


       ROLE_ADDUPDATE


       ROLE_SEARCH
2. Add Jboss Security domain name in jboss-web.xml

   java:/jaas/other
        true

   - Add users and roles in application-users.properties and applications-roles.properties (see documentatin of Jboss for Command Line Interface)
   - You can even authorize at granular level like EJB method level using @RolesAllowed, @PermitAll, @DenyAll etc if you are using EJBs